# MVC5 how to merge business tables to the IdentityDbContext via EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Just started using MVC 5 web application. I found that the identity2.0 is little bit confused to work on.

Basically, 
1) I would like to use one DbContext (entity), aka, one connection to one database. 
2) Because after creating the MVc 5 application, the ApplicationDbContext is generated by mvc automatically. That means once I run the application, few tables will be created on the database(via connection string) by the code first. I am ok with the identityDbContext and all the Identity 2.0 functionalities, but how to adding other tables (for the business) to the ApplicatonDbContext?

I found a very good article below, but the senario is still to use two DbContext, one for Identity and one for business.

http://danieleagle.com/blog/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/

Would anyone be so kind to post some ideas here? Links, design assumptions.

Regards

Comment: add your `DbSet<T>` objects for your business entities in the declaration for the `ApplicationDbContext`, and away you go!  Please note, there is no merging going on, and Identity 2.0 is just a series of classes that are built around Entity Framework, they don't change how Entity Framework works.

Comment: If I add DbSets (business entities) as the properties of ApplicationDbContext, will business entites become the code first as well? I would like to build them as database first. Cheers

Comment: My recommendation is that you use a hybrid approach, it's what the newer EF builds are moving toward anyway.  You can use CodeFirst to design your entities, but use a database initializer which does not modify your SQL.  Unless you really can't live without the Database Wizard pages;  If you *must* have the Database Wizards, then you have no choice but to have 2 contexts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I separate my application context from ApplicationDbContext used for identity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258164/should-i-separate-my-application-context-from-applicationdbcontext-used-for-iden)